# How to dry a plastic-and-fabric bag overnight

Tags: water, container

My lunch bag got wet at work today. It has a flexible plastic lining, inside a fabric bag. It must also have something between the plastic and the fabric to keep its box-like shape. It's about 12" x 8" x 6". The brand is Embark.

[image]

I dried out the inside with paper towels, but I want to dry the whole thing thoroughly before I use it tomorrow morning.

**How can I dry my bag completely overnight?**

Thoughts:

- I currently have it in the refrigerator, even though water evaporates more slowly at colder temperatures, because refrigerators remove moisture from the air as they cool it.
- I don't want to put my bag in my clothes dryer, because I'm afraid the heat would melt the plastic lining. I am not sure if a "cool" or "tumble only" setting would damage the shape of the bag or the plastic lining.
- I thought about placing the bag in front of an air conditioning output vent, since that air is especially dry, but they're up near the ceiling and very hard to access.

Comment: Hang the bag (use a coat hanger?) in front of the a/c vent with the lining pulled-out (bloused) so that there's a larger air gap between the lining and the stiffer liner FWIW. If you stuff it with crumpled paper, it may hold its shape better in the dryer with a little heat. It might take longer than your deadline allows. Good luck.

Comment: @Stan I didn't pay extra for the facbric bag, so I had to change my question's subject back to simple fabric.

Answer (score 1):

Hang the lunchbox using a clothes hanger place it in front of a fan and let it airdry overnight. Position the fan to make sure the bag gets maximum air to dry it faster. That should remove all of the moisture in and out of the lunchbox overnight.

Comment: Good suggestion. I didn't have access to a fan, though.